# Why does Python say file does not exist?

Tags: python, windows-xp, operating-system, system

I am writing a small script which will print if a file exists or not.

But it always says that the file does not exist, even though the file actually exists.

Code:

```
file = exists(macinput+".py")
print file
if file == "True":
   print macinput+" command not found"
elif file == "True":
   print os.getcwd()
   os.system("python "+macinput+".py")
   print file
```

Comment: You might want to take another look at the `if`/`elif` statements.

Comment: taking "file" as a variable name is not a very good idea. if you want to open a file later in the namespace you get problems.

Answer (score 2):

You should not compare with "True", but with True.

Also, you compare both in the if and the elif with "True".

instead of

```
if file == "True":
    print macinput + " command not found"
```

try this:

```
file = exists(macinput+".py")
print "file truth value: ", file

if file:
    print macinput + " command found"
else:
    print macinput + " command NOT found"
```

and remove the elif...

Comment: Don't compare to boolean literals! It's like saying "If it is true that..." instead of just "If..." in ordinary speech.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing `"True"` instead of `True`. Also, your `if` and `elif` statements are the same.

```
if not file:
   print macinput+" command not found"
else:
   print os.getcwd()
   os.system("python "+macinput+".py")
   print file
```

Comment: And comparison with `True` is redundant (just use `if file`), and comparision with `False` is `not` (just use `if not file` or `else`).

Answer (score 2):

Correcting logic, and making your code a little more 'pythonic'

```
import os
filename = macinput + ".py"
file_exists = os.path.isfile(filename)
print file_exists
if file_exists:
   print os.getcwd()
   os.system("python {0}".format(filename))
   print file_exists
else:
   print '{0} not found'.format(filename)
```